# Failing condition on Lebesgue's Dominated Convergence Theorem

Tags: measure-theory, lebesgue-integral

I've been given the following conditions on a sequence of functions $f_k:\mathbb N\to [0,+\infty)$

1. $f_k(n)\to0$ as $k\to \infty$ for every $n\in\mathbb N$.
2. $\int f_k\text{d}\mu=1$ for every $k$.

Obviously we can't interchange limit and integral, so Lebesgue's Dominated Convergence Theorem doesn't apply here; but, what condition is failing?

I've been trying to prove that if there is some $g:\mathbb N\to [0,+\infty)$ such that $f_k(n)\leq g(n)$ for every $n\in\mathbb N$ then such $g$ cannot be $L^1$, meaning that we'd have $\int g\text{d}\mu=+\infty$. How can I proceed?

Any help will be appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Comment: An example $f_k$ is $$ f_k(n) = \begin{cases}1 ,& k =n \\ 0 ,& \text{otherwise} \end{cases} \text{.}  $$  What $g$ is forced in this case?  Another example is $$ f_k(n) = \begin{cases} 1/k ,& 1 \leq n \leq k \\ 0 ,& \text{otherwise} \end{cases} \text{.} $$ What $g$ is forced in this case?

Comment: I see that $g(n)=1\,\forall n\in\mathbb N$ in the first case and in the second case, but what about the general case?

Comment: How do I force $g$ to have an infinite integral?

Comment: You have not understood the second case.

Comment: Could you elaborate?

Comment: The forced $g$ in the second case is not constant.  That $g$ is still not integrable.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/133245/discussion-between-darsen-and-eric-towers).